# JQgrid Syntax error, unrecognized expression on return value from custom_value function

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, syntax-error, custom-controls, ampersand

For a simple view of problem please check: http://jsfiddle.net/9bmrjnwe/2/ (to generate the error: click on any row for editing. Then click on alternative row and then click back on the previously edited row. The error will popup.

Thanks

I'm new to JQuery. I have a JQgrid on my webpage containing a custom control while in editing mode. This custom control basically is a "html select" with select2. here is the relevant code of the JQgrid column:

```
        editoptions: {
            custom_element: function (value, options) {

                var val = $(value);
                var output = [];
                output.push("<select id = 'JQGridSelectCol1' width=900>");
                output.push('<option value= 101> ABC & XYZ </option>');
                output.push('<option value= 102> ABC XYZ </option>');
                output.push("</select>");
                var selectText = output.join('');

                $OuterDiv = $("<div id='SelectDivCol1'></div>");
                $OuterDiv.append(selectText);

                $select = $OuterDiv.children("#JQGridSelectCol1");

                var value2 = $("#vEntries").jqGrid('getCell', lastSel, 'Code');
                $select.val(value2);

                return $OuterDiv;

            },
           custom_value: function myvalue(elem, operation, value) {
                if (operation === 'get') {
                    return $(elem).find(":selected").text();
               }
           },
```

Now everything is working fine until I click on a row where in that column the selected text of  contains ampersand character (&) and an error pops up with message: "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ABC & XYZ" where "ABC & XYZ" is my selected text of . I tried to debug through Chrome and found the error on this line:

https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/c2ceeced1230ab7e91570c3d9a1400f3e7f0f8ed/js/grid.common.js#L490

Can anyone guide me in this regard?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: the error is in `custom_element`, but you included only the code of `custom_value`. Could you include more full code?

Comment: @Oleg: The error appears exactly when JQGrid tries to get text value from grid column of the particular row for and tries to render "html select" for editing (I'm using rowediting). For the sake of simplicity, I've put a very simple code and removed the select2 also. still receiving the error : "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ABC & XYZ". If I Select other option (without ampersand character) from the combobox and save it and go back it would not produce any error. Thanks

Comment: @Oleg:  http://jsfiddle.net/9bmrjnwe/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the line

```
var val = $(value);
```

of `custom_element`. You should remove the line. If you need to get the value from the cell you need use something like `$OuterDiv.append($(selectText).val(value));` instead of `$OuterDiv.append(selectText);`, but you should take in consideration that

Moreover I recommend you remove all ids from HTML elements created in `custom_element` to be sure that you will never have id duplicates.

Comment: Questions:
How did you figure out this problem? I tried from Chrome debugging tools but could no succeeded.

secondly, the line $OuterDiv.append(selectText); is just to append the HTML which was generated in above statement "var selectText = output.join('');". am I doing wrong?

Thirdly, regarding not using ids in HTML elements here so what could be the substitute for selecting html select tag "$select = $OuterDiv.children("#JQGridSelectCol1");" class?

Thank you once again for your help.

Comment: @developer: You are welcome! I'm a little busy now. I will answer you later today or tomorrow.

Comment: @developer: Look at http://jsfiddle.net/9bmrjnwe/9/. It uses no ids and it seems to work.

Comment: Excellent, you made it so simple. Thank you. Can you please tell me the way you figure out the error in line 

var val = $(value);

I'm asking you because I spent a lot of time to locate where the error is but could not find the right place. Thanks once again for your time.

Comment: @developer: You are welcome! It was very simple. I just debugged the code step by step and I could see that you try to make `$("ABC & XYZ")`, but `"ABC & XYZ"` is of cause not a HTML fragment. Many years ago I worked as mathematician and my chief repeat many times that by working in the team one get the best results. It you have stop in your work you should show you middle results to somebody. Either you yourself will find the error during the presentation or another person will solve the problem. It's much more difficult to find the error own code and it's much more simple in the foreign one.

Comment: true, one of my teacher used to say "Do you need another pair of eyes for your code to debug" :) Thank you for saving my day.

Comment: @developer: Exactly! You are welcome and best wishes!